# why my variable wont change to what it should be in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so when im running the "Running" code, my moveSpeed variable wont change to 4. this is happening when im adding the "Crouching" code. when i deleted or commented the crouching code, my running code works well

so here is my code

```
    //Running
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        moveSpeed = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        moveSpeed = 2;
    }

    //Crouching
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true);
        moveSpeed = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);
        moveSpeed = 2;
    }
```

im newbie at game dev, i'd appreciate any advice

Comment: is this in your update function?

Comment: i suggest you add this to the `FixedUpdate()` function

Comment: yes i put it in update method, why?

Comment: its best to do movement or physics logic in fixedupdate,

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Input detection shouldnt be on the FixedUpdate() function because it should run every frame of the game not per physical tick

Comment: @IamHoussam FixedUpdate is ran twice per frame tick,https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are not pressing the C and the moveSpeed is "stuck" on 2.
If the code is running it runs from top to bottom, so when you are pressing the left shift it sets the move speed to 4. After this is checks the C, when this is not true it will override the 4 with 2.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        moveSpeed = 4;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true);
        moveSpeed = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        moveSpeed = 2;
    }
```

Comment: holy cow, why didnt i think of this. thanks bro u helped me a lot.

Comment: Good to hear that, i am happy to help :)